# Put separator on view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to put separator on `NSView` Programmatically? I have tried this :

```
NSView *right = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(319, 0, 1, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self.view addSubView:right];
```

but it is not working, please suggest what is wrong with this snippet or if there is another way to do this

Comment: check in NSLog(), that self.view.frame is not empty in the moment you r createnif right view

Comment: i am getting value alex

Answer (score 0):

```
NSView *right = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(319, 0, 1, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[right.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.view addSubView:right];
```

I think that's because you have added `right` but you can't see it. try set background color.

Comment: we can set background colour for IOS but how to set for MAC OS, this is the problem ,thanks for your answer

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with Mac OS, but maybe you can try set view's layer background color.@PRSingh

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1)  Make your own NSView subclass for the self.view object.  Then in that subclass define a drawRect method to draw the separator:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)r {
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(319., 0, 1., self.view.bounds.size.height));
}
```

2)  Alternatively, you can make a custom NSView subclass that has a backgroundColor property.  Then create a drawRect in that NSView subclass to fill the entire view with that color:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)r {
    [self.backgroundColor set];
    NSRectFill(r);
}
```

Comment: Don't do any of those. Just use `NSBox`. It's built in to AppKit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSBox` to draw a separating line.

Here's how I suggest you do it:

```
    // Make the box one point wide, spanning the right edge of the view.
    let viewBounds = view.bounds
    let box = NSBox(frame:
        CGRect(x: viewBounds.maxX - 1, y: viewBounds.minY,
               width: 1, height: viewBounds.maxY))

    // Tell AppKit to stretch the box vertically when the view resizes,
    // and to keep it against the right edge of the view.
    box.autoresizingMask = [.height, .minXMargin]

    // Set the appearance of the box to solid red.
    box.boxType = .custom
    box.fillColor = .red
    box.borderType = .noBorder

    view.addSubview(box)
```